# Turn on semantic mode for C/C++

Tags: auto-complete-mode, c++, syntax, cedet

I got these lines:

```
;; turn on semantic
(semantic-mode 1)

;; define a function which adds semantic as backup to auto-complete
(defun my:add-semantic-to-autocomplete()
  (add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-sources-semantic))

(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my:add-semantic-to-autocomplete)
```

From this video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ib914gNr0ys).But for me it does not work at all.Save me please,i lost all day fighting with it...

Comment: Have you installed auto-complete?  Please try to detail what you do, what you expect and what happens instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mistyped your auto-complete source symbol.

It should be `'ac-source-semantic`, not `'ac-source(S)-semantic`

Comment: I'm such an idiot,thank you very much tho,appreciate your help.

Comment: What do you think about irony mode,is it the best mode for c/c++?

Comment: I have not used it, I use company-clang with flycheck. However, I do not frequently write C or C++ so my knowledge of what is best is limited.

Comment: Not fly-make?  @Jordon Biondo